# AngularJS ng-class Expression Not Working Properly?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-class

I am using `ng-repeat` to list out the number of home runs vs away run in a simple table.
I am applying a class based on which team is winning using the following snippet of code:

```
  <tr ng-class="{winning : game.linescore.r.home > game.linescore.r.away}">
    <td>{{ game.home_team_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ game.linescore.r.home }}</td>
  </tr>
```

The code works if the number of home runs is greater than the number of away runs but only if this number is less than 10.

Example:

Works As Expected: 9 > 5

Does Not Work: 11 > 5

I am wondering does anyone know how overcome this issue?

Comment: Are your scores numbers or strings? `11 > 5` but `'11' < '5'`

Comment: I am retrieving the data from a JSON API feed so I'd need to convert it to numbers first. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your values are strings, then it makes sense, as `'9' > '5'` but `'11' < '5'`. You'll need to convert to integer with e.g. `parseInt`.